# How to solve this error in python selenium the error message that I am getting is TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, pom.xml

I am getting this error when clicking on a submenu under a parent menu, please help me out to solve this problem, The error occurs when the script calls the 'Submenu method'

```
enter code here
```

## This below class contain all the locators of the page

```
class workflow_locator:
    # Create a new workflow locator
    dropdown_xpath = "(//DIV[@class='btn-group dropdown'])[1]"
    admin_menu_xpath = "(//A[@class='dropdown-item'])[3]"
    breadcrumb_xpath = "(//DIV[@class='left-menu-toggle'])[1]"
    workflow_menu_xpath = "(//A[@_ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c5=''])[31]"
    workflow_submenu_xpath = "(//A[@href='/admin/workflows'])"
    new_btn_xpath = "(//DIV[text()=' New'])"
    workflow_name_xpath = "(//INPUT[@id='name'])[1]"
    workflow_description_xpath = "(//TEXTAREA[@id='description'])[2]"
    active_toggle_xpath = "(//SPAN[@class='slider'])"
    add_button_xpath = "(//BUTTON[@class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'])[text()='Add']"


#This class define the action method of the below test class
from Resources.Workflow_locator import workflow_locator
class CreateWorkflow(workflow_locator):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def click_drop_down_menu(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.dropdown_xpath).click()

    def select_admin_from_the_drop_down_menu(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.admin_menu_xpath).click()

    def click_breadcrumb_menu(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.breadcrumb_xpath).click()

    def click_workflow_menu(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.workflow_menu_xpath).click()
    def click_workflow_sub_menu(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.click_workflow_sub_menu).click()

# This is a test class
     def test_workflow(self, setup):
            self.driver = setup
            self.driver.get(self.base_url)
            self.driver.maximize_window()
            self.lp = Login(self.driver)
            self.lp.set_Username(self.username)
            self.lp.click_next_btn()
            self.lp.set_password(self.Password)
            self.lp.click_signin_btn()
            self.lp.click_confirm_btn()
            self.driver.get_screenshot_as_file(".\\Screenshoots\\login.png")
            self.logger.info("############ User is successfully logged in ########### ")
            print("Login is successfully completed")
            self.logger.info("######### Creating WorkFlow #########")
            self.wf=CreateWorkflow(self.driver)
            self.wf.click_drop_down_menu()
            self.wf.select_admin_from_the_drop_down_menu()
            self.wf.click_breadcrumb_menu()
            self.wf.click_workflow_menu()
            self.wf.click_workflow_sub_menu()
```

The exception I can see is

def default(self, o):
"""Implement this method in a subclass such that it returns
a serializable object for `o`, or calls the base implementation
(to raise a `TypeError`).

```
    For example, to support arbitrary iterators, you could
    implement default like this::

        def default(self, o):
            try:
                iterable = iter(o)
            except TypeError:
                pass
            else:
                return list(iterable)
            # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
            return JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

    """
```

> ```
>   raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
> ```

```
                    f'is not JSON serializable')
```

E       TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Egf.png)

Comment: What is `CreateWorkflow`? Should I know this? Doesn't sound like an error in Selenium necessarily. Show us the stack trace.

Comment: hI @Booboo CreateWorkflow is a class where I have defined the action method of a web page
class CreateWorkflow(workflow_locator):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def click_workflow_sub_menu(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.click_workflow_sub_menu).click()

Comment: It's best to put that code in your question along with the stack trace

Comment: Hi @Booboo please check the code now

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Still no stacktrace! And in what class is method `default` defined?

Comment: Hi @Booboo  please check the stack image I have attached above

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
def click_workflow_menu(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.workflow_menu_xpath).click()
def click_workflow_sub_menu(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.click_workflow_sub_menu).click()
```

When you call `self.click_workflow_sub_menu()`, this is what happens:

1. `self.click_workflow_sub_menu` is evaluated. But this evaluates to a bound method and not a valid xpath expression.
2. `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath` is invoked with the result from step 1, which is not a valid xpath expression, and an exception results.

I believe that is your problem. What you probably meant was:

```
def click_workflow_sub_menu(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.workflow_submenu_xpath).click()
```